# My site doesnt open from iPhone (iOS 11)?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, iphone

I have some problems with my website. My site is coded in HTML,CSS and JS.
Everywhere works perfect, Desktop (all browsers), Android (All browsers), in iPhone(iOS.11) doesn't work!!!

I think there may be two problems: 
   1. When i open the site, i have Loading Page script, and in iPhone it stops there and doesnt open the site. 
   2. The problem may also be with the new iOS 11, because with earlier iOS(10) was working very well.

Any suggestion, or any site which i can check my errors (debugg) or..? 
google didn't solve my problem so i decided to ask, but still can't find the problem!!!

Thanks.

Comment: If you plug your iPhone into a Mac and launch (desktop) Safari, you can debug your iPhone web browser. [Instructions](https://appletoolbox.com/2014/05/use-web-inspector-debug-mobile-safari/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an OSX available you can enable remote debug and see what's happening, most likely something is breaking based on something not being available.

Comment: don't have OSX. :(